# TypeScript автоматическая подстановка ключей и при создании объекта и при его использовании

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, typescript-типы

Имеется вот такой код на typescript:

```typescript
export type TaskType = 'addCookie' | 'addLocalStorageValue' | 'addSessionStorageValue' | 'doRequest'
export type Tasks<Keys extends string|number> = {
    readonly [Key in Keys]: Task
}
type Task= {
    task: TaskType
}

const specifics = {
    'www.digitalocean.com': {
        task: 'doRequest'
    },
    'example.com': {
        task: 'doRequest'
    },

} as const;

export type SpecificsDomains = keyof typeof specifics;

export const specificDomains: Tasks<SpecificsDomains> = specifics
```

при использовании экспортированного объекта в другом файле, отлично работает и подстановка  ключей объектов, и типизация значений объекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при добавлении новых полей в сам объект, IDE не понимает, что по каждому из ключей я жду поле типа `Task` и не подставляет из-за этого возможные значения `TaskType`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя судя по подчеркиванию на 24й строке, IDE понимает, что specificDomains, учитывая типы, из такого объекта получить уже не получится.

Тогда я пытаюсь добавить аннотацию типа прямо при объявлении объекта (11я строка):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если так сделать, аннотация типов действительно начинает работать корректно, однако в экспортированном модуле (и вообще везде при использовании переменной specificDomains) IDE перестает понимать, какие ключи есть в объекте, а каких нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Здесь как видно, не подчеркивает красным ключ, которого нет, и не предлагает подставить ключ, который есть.)

Я пробовал подставить переменной `specifics` тип `Tasks<SpecificsDomains>`, но в таком случае получаю ошибку `TS2502`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы и аннотации типов ключей объекта при его дополении работали, и при этом в других модулях ключи понимались?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй генерик, чтобы получить создать константу, расширяющую тип

```
type Task = {a: 1};

function widenTaskRecors<T extends Record<string, Task>>(v: T): T{
  return v
}

/**
 * let x: {
 *     a: {
 *         a: 1;
 *     };
 * }
 */
let x = widenTaskRecors({
  'a': {a: 1}
})
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNZQLxQN5wFxQIwC+A3AFAkBmArgHYDGwAlgPbVQDuDAJhNfMgEoRaTAE4IAPDCgQAHsB6cEUQcJGdxCYCIbUA5gBpYiJAD4TACgBuuGAEobGElCgiIwSiNaWSBMgHoAKgCnAKgAGzcoGVxHKFDnZxxMEITUxNw8Uji04hTfOL8SCOAotHYuHj4kFVEEc1ioAHI4Rpikwh9bIA